# Get hash value using bash

Tags: ios, bash

I need to get the PID value out of a variable(containing hash data) using BASH. eval errors because of the array inside of it.  This script is on an iPhone.

```
eval "$(launchctl list com.3radicateRD)"

eval: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
eval: line 10: `  "ProgramArguments" = ('
------------------------------------------------------
{
        "Label" = "com.3radicateRD";
        "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "System";
        "OnDemand" = false;
        "LastExitStatus" = 0;
        "PID" = 6810;
        "TimeOut" = 30;
        "ProgramArguments" = (
                "bash";
                "/var/mobile/Library/3radicateRD/3radicateRD";
        );
};
```

Comment: `eval` is a bash builtin that executes the code you give it as though it was bash code.  You are giving it the output of the `launchctl` command.  That is NOT bash code.  There is absolutely no sense in putting `eval` there.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know bash on IPhone (or launchctl for that matter). But normally you would need to get the line containing `"PID" = ...`, remove quotes, semicolons, spaces and tabs from that and pass that result to `eval`. You can do that using `grep` and `sed`:

```
eval $(launchctl list com.3radicateRD | grep '"PID"' | sed 's/["; \t]//g')
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use eval. Just execute your program normally.

```
launchctl list com.3radicateRD | awk '/PID/{print $3}'
```

Update:
I don't have iphone, so i am guess there is bash?

```
launchctl list com.3radicateRD | while read line
do
  case "$line" in 
   *PID* )
     set -- $line
     echo $3
  esac
done
```

And if you have sed,

```
launchctl list com.3radicateRD | sed '/PID/s/.*= //;s/;//'
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, iPhone doesn't have an awk binary so it didn't work in this case.